# Add Dcom protocol through wmi properties programmatically

Tags: powershell, wmi, dcom

In order to use wmi fixed port in my server, I need to do the following:

1.Open Component Services

2.Open the Dcom Config

3.Open Windows Management and Instrumentation Properties

4.Go to the Endpoints tab

5.Press Add

6.Choose Connection-oriented TCP/IP and Use static endpoint with a chosen port

I would like to do it programmatically. I tried to do it using powershell, and was able to get the WMI Object using this line of code:

```
$wmiobj = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter 'Description="Windows Management and Instrumentation"'
```

But I didn't realize how I can use this object to change the settings, even after searching the web and the site. I did find a list of properties, like the AppID and the LocalService name, but no methods I can use to change the right settings.

How can I use this object to change the wmi settings like I mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `$wmiobj.Property = "test"; $wmiobj.put()` ofc replace "Property" with the Property you want to set